# Rails: How to group by nested association?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, group-by

I have a Follow model with `user_id` and `track_id`. The Track model has an `artist_id` field.

What I want to do is count which artists have the most followers, but since users follow "tracks" and not "artists", I need to figure out how to do a count through the tracks.

So, what I was thinking was to do some sort of group by on a nested association. i.e. Group the Follow records by "track -> artist_id", somehow.

Then I could count the number of users for each.

Is that even possible? Is there more info that would be useful here?

Comment: Can you show your associations? `belongs_to` and `has_many` and such?

Comment: what's the association between Track and Artist ? has_one or has_many ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [`has_many :through`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_many) to establish the Artist <-> Tracks <-> User relationship.

```
class Artist < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :tracks
  has_many :users, through: :tracks
end

class Follow < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :track
end

class Track < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :artist
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users, join_table: :follows
end

class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :tracks
  has_many :artists, through: :tracks, join_table: :follows
end
```

Then Rails can take care of the joins between `Artist` and `User`.

```
Artist.includes(:users).group(:id).count("users.id")
```